# regId giving empty in android gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi in the below code I am getting the regId showing empty.but username and password values working perfectly.But I am not getting why that device id was showing empty.

after clicking the register button it's showing registered with GCM.

**class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // label to display gcm messages
    TextView lblMessage;

    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public static String username;
    public static String password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        username = i.getStringExtra("username");
        password = i.getStringExtra("password");        

        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.              
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, username, password, regId);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }       

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**logcat**

```
04-22 04:05:46.389: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(2355): > Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@4175aa98
```

Comment: Have you generate a API Key from Google API Console?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes I did

Comment: Please take note that C2DM has been deprecated and will be shut down completely on July 30, 2015. If you are only just about to include messaging in your app, I highly recommend that you use the newer GoogleCloudMessaging API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project using google's console with the same name as application's name in eclipse helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: problem may be due to your registration id. have you enable gcm service in console?

Comment: Posting 'password=111&username=STD112&regId=APA91bHMluVoJzPY6-6KkbZqdrEqxYsE_hdbQzY1aMZFTZBUvheXUhfFgUIV3EoKVpeeR4IC9aacqS3RoWY8oG3GSadkg6X7ea38ydwJie_Bbwx4-tZXBllgkhUAt0srviu6Qn0nEImN1lPhNibHKLhwXiN94Hv4vA' to http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php
04-22 08:00:37.330: E/URL(1188): > http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php

Comment: For the console it's posting these values

Answer (score 0):

Try This... Fisrt Check google play service

```
  if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        mRegistrationId = getRegistrationId(mContext);

        if (mRegistrationId.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                registerInBackground(senderId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unsupported for this            device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", mRegistrationId);
                        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services found.");
    }
```

Checking google play service

```
  private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Get RegistrationId is here

```
   private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    assert registrationId != null;
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }

    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}
```

And here is registerInBackground Async Task

```
    private void registerInBackground(final String senderID) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
                }
                try {
                    mRegistrationId = gcm.register(senderID);
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unsupported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + mRegistrationId;


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, s);
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

This is working for me. Hope It will help you.

Comment: yesterday i did with same device it's working suppose the device is not supported means it won't work

Comment: I think, only google play service doesn't support. If Device is having Android. It is supported device.